# Is there a way to move home controls in control center?

Tags: iphone, homekit, control-center

I enabled home controls in control center. I have 6 favorites that display in control center. However, I use them less frequently than the custom control center items that appear below them (just off screen on a second gen iPhone SE). It's really annoying to have to scroll to turn on the flashlight, which I use all the time.

Is there any way to either:

1. move the home controls to the bottom?
2. Add alternative home controls (like via *Siri shortcut* or something) amongst the custom items below (i.e. with the official "home controls disabled")?
3. At least show only 1 row of home controls (like the big button and 2 favorites) or will a second row be filled in with frequent items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no way to move the buttons resulting from the "Show Home Controls" toggle to a different location.
2. There is no way to add custom home-related buttons other than a single home button.  That single home button can be placed anywhere among the custom-added buttons and opens a sub-control-center-view, defaulting to your home favorites.
3. There is no way to specify the selection and ordering of the frequently used home controls resulting from the "Show Home Controls" toggle

So the best you can do is disable the "Show Home Controls" toggle and add the custom home button, placing it where you want among the custom-added buttons.